# How get a GIF from .SWF file with AS3 and Binary?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, binary, gif

I have a SWF file that should display an animated image. This file contains pictures, a file ActionScript 3.0 and several Binary files.

My question is, how get a GIF of the result of this SWF file ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the AS3 code used to animate the picture? You might have to record the SWF in action and then convert recorded output to GIF. By record I mean use a screen grabber that either does multiple shots per second or records screen area/window as a video... Just find a preferred (freeware) tool via web search

Comment: Alternatively if you can code with AS3, just load the SWF into your app and then write your own "recorder" code.

Answer (score 1):

To make a GIF Image in Flash, go to Publish Settings in properties, and click the box next to GIF Image then click publish.

Also make sure that it works by uploading it online.

Hope this helps

Comment: What is the exact name of the software please  ? I've Adobe Animate CC, SWF Decompiler Thrillix !

Comment: I can't import a SWF file in Adobe Animate CC. How you do ?

Comment: I am not familiar with Adobe Animate CC. 
But In Flash Professional CS6 you have to click File and select the SWF
you wish to import to import the SWF.

Here is a link that might be helpful: https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/kb/edit-import-swf-file.html